# Can't find table/object error when running an index rebuild

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am running a index rebuild script:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName,' ',90)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

END

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

but it fails with the error "Msg 2501, Level 16, State 45, Line 13
Cannot find a table or object with the name "ServiceDeploymentsTable". Check the system catalog."

The script is from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-for-rebuilding-all-8d079754

I have a felling the table might belong to a different object (like dbo or something else) but I don't know how to confirm that or modify the script to deal with that. Or maybe I am compleatly off base.

How can I best deal with this error and rebuild all the indexs in the database?

Comment: You should stop using deprecated commands from decade old scripts. This is a free and up to date solution: ola.hallengren.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances are the the table you are attempting to reindex exists in a different schema than the default, and as such you will not find it.

The following update should allow you to obtain that table.

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(512)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName,' ',90)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

END

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

A couple of things that you should note, [DBCC DBREINDEX is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-dbreindex-transact-sql), you should really be using [ALTER INDEX REBUILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql) instead. As an additional item, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel there are free solutions out there that have been written by folks with many years of experience, such as [Minionware Reindex](http://minionware.net/reindex/). These are designed to be quickly and easily deployed and to provide simple management.